# How to ignore some directory in htpasswd?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I set some `htaccess` with `htpasswd` on my server. Here is it's content:

```
Order Allow,Deny
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
```

It works for all `/var/www/*` directories.

Is it possible to ignore some of that `/var/www/*` directories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place those directives in a [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) directive, so they only apply to one directory.